# Multi-shipping depending on specific product attribute

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping-methods, multishipping

I have been struggling hard from a few days to find out a way for multi shipping of products depending on product type (type is not magento's type where as it is custom attribute i.e type can be grocery, non-grocery)

so, let me explain my problem:

I have two types of items in my store, one are grocery and other are non-grocery. When a user add these items to cart, I need to show him two groups of products(grocery, non-grocery). The grocery items can be shipped in one hour while others cannot be. So I need to show user separate shipping methods available for both the groups i.e user can have options as MethodA, MethodB, MethodC for grocery-group and MethodB, MethodC, MethodD for non-grocery-group.

**Note**: The products as grocery, non-grocery are separated on the basis of some flag in product attributes, moreover the address will be the same for each group.

I didn't find any extension which can do so, from where should I start? should I override the functionality of Multi-shipping? Please suggest me the ways to get it done!

Comment: That will require several elements to change. You need to force multishipping checkout if there is a mix, then divide cart to 2 parts in multishipping and block ability to change it, and finally hook into getShippingRates to handle enabled/disabled there. It is doable but this would be probably even ~100h of work. I would recommend thinking about limiting cart to only 1 type in a way that first item defines what can be in cart and checking before add to cart if next item is from the same category. If not show info to first place order for existing items before adding new ones.

Comment: @Zefiryn it's our business case where we need to have multi sipping for whole cart items, we need to show customer if he needs grocery items in less time, each shipping method is defined by the number of hours to deliver the products.

Comment: The way multishipping works in Magento is splitting cart into n orders as by design order may have only 1 shipping method. If your store require to have 1 checkout process for mixed cart then I am afraid you will need to write it yourself or find a company with developers capable to do that.

Comment: @Zefiryn, I need to split the order into two, yes you are right. What I need is checkout with providing user two different group of checkboxes to select shipping method for each group of items, is there any extension (paid/unpaid) available for this? I will be really thankful!

Comment: Just shooting in the dark here. Have you found a solution to this?